# How to get Eclipse EE to build classes in WEB-INF/classes (or better approach)

Tags: linux, eclipse, tomcat7

The default for Eclipse EE seems to be to build java code in build/classes not in WEB-INF/classes or WEB-INF/lib/my.jar.  I can create a .war file which has the entire project, but then every time I build, I have to manually generate the war file.  My current setup which has the WebContents directory symbolic linked to /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT, in which case all the web pages are by definition in the right place, but the code is not there.

I'm willing to take a suggestion on how to get this to happen automatically, but I would like to know WHY there should be the need in the first place?  Why would I want to have my build directory for a web application anywhere other than the directory where it should be executed?  Is there any way to get eclipse to build the !%*@% class files in a sane place, or is there in fact a reason why an EE app would have code that does not go on the server?  Is there something simple that I can add to trigger a rule in ant or mvn to move the code to the right place?

Compounding this problem, I am switching over to Ubuntu (Not that this works under windows at the moment either).
I was getting weird errors, and it turns out I didn't have jdk7 installed.
So I installed it, but how do I even know what java is being used to run tomcat and eclipse?  How do I know it will use jdk7 and not the one that was used before? On windows, when I tried to run Eclipse, it gave a straightforward error when Java wasn't installed so this never happened.

I type javac -version and get the correct one, but this does not guarantee that some service like tomcat7 will use the same one.

The error (same on Windows)

```
An error occurred at line: 3 in the jsp file: /demos/post.jsp
ReadBody cannot be resolved to a type
1: <%@ page import="org.adastraeducation.liquiz.servlet.*" %>
2: <%
3:   ReadBody b;
4: %>
5: <html>
6: <body>
```

The current (ridiculous) way to stop this error is:

```
   cd build/classes
   jar -cf my.jar org
   sudo mv my.jar /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib
   sudo service tomcat7 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse Web Tools](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) can manage building and packaging a web-app (WAR) and automatically running it on a local server of your choice. This includes re-deployment when changes are made, debugging, etc. But you have to create or configure your project as a Dynamic Web project for Eclipse to know to do that for you.

For starters, you'll need to either [download](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) the **Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers** package or use the [Eclipse Installer](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/installer.php) to get it. Then you can peruse the Web Tools help (for example, start [here](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fccwtover.html&cp=79_0_0)).

Comment: Actually the project is a Dynamic Web project.

Under Linux, eclipse is not generating the list of different tomcat servers that can be dynamically launched as in Windows.  I suppose that is a separate question.